# Infinite Sequences-calculus

Tags: calculus

Suppose sequence $\{A_n\}$ converges to $L_1$ and $\{B_n\}$ converges to $L_2$.
How can I use the definition of limit of sequence to show this:
If $A_n\ge B_n$ for all $n=1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$ then $L_1\ge L_2$.

Anyone can help or give hints? thanks!
It seem very logical but hard to prove using definition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $L_1 < L_2$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exist positive integers $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that

$$n \geqslant N_1 \implies |A_n - L_1| < \epsilon \implies A_n < L_1 + \epsilon,
\\n \geqslant N_2 \implies |B_n - L_2| < \epsilon \implies B_n > L_2 - \epsilon.$$

Take $N = \max(N_1,N_2)$ and $\epsilon = \frac{L_2-L_1}{2}.$

Then if $n \geqslant N$ we have

$$A_n < L_1 +\frac{L_2-L_1}{2} = \frac{L_2+L_1}{2} =  L_2 -\frac{L_2-L_1}{2} < B_n,$$

which contradicts  $A_n \geqslant B_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: what is the use of the first line L1<L2?

Comment: This is  proof by contradiction. We assume the conclusion of the theorem is false and using the definition of a limit find a contradiction - thereby by showing the theorem is true.

Comment: Since $A_n \to L_1$ each term must be inside a small interval around $L_1$ for sufficiently large $n$.  Similarly for $B_n$.  Unless $L_1 \geqslant L_2$ we can place the small intervals so that $A_n < B_n$ for large $n$ which is impossible given $A_n \geqslant B_n$.

Comment: There is no way around proof by contradiction here. If you say $A_n-B_n$ is nonnegative  and implies the limit $L_1-L_2$ is obviously nonnegative -- that assertion still requires proof -- in the same way I show. You would assume $L_1-L_2 < 0$ and show that for large enough $n$, $A_n-B_n$ falls in an interval around the limit for which all points are negative -- contradicting $A_n-B_n \geqslant 0$. Triangle inequality does not help either since $|L_1-L_2| \leqslant |L_1 - A_n|+|L_2-B_n|$ tells you nothing about the sign of $L_1-L_2$.

Comment: @RRF I know you are using proof by contradiction and understands your proof "on surface". How would you know what epsilon to be used?and Could you explain to me in simple language how you construct this proof(the main idea behind)?

Comment: Assume $L_1 < L_2$. Consider the intervals $I_1 = (L_1-(L_2-L_1)/2,L_1+ (L_2-L_1)/2))$ and $I_2 = (L_2-(L_2-L_1)/2,L_2+ (L_2-L_1)/2))$.  If $n$ is large enough we have $A_n \in I_1$ since $A_n \to L_1$ and we have $B_n \in I_2$ since $B_n \to L_1$

Comment: But that means $A_n$ is less than the right endpoint of $I_1$ and $B_n$ is greater than the left endpoint of $I_2$. These endpoints are the midpoint $(L_1 + L_2)/2$. This means $A_n < B_n$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: so the key idea is: We fix the endpoint for both intervals to be the same(which will also determine the epsilon).And then assume L1<L2 to deduce the contradiction.

Comment: Yes.  First assume $L_1 < L_2$. Then put non-overlapping open intervals around the limits. I chose the intervals so they shared the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence $\{c_n\}_n$ converges to a limit $\ell<0$, then picking $\varepsilon=-\ell/2$ in the definition of limit you conclude that eventually $c_n<0$. Now define $c_n=A_n-B_n$ and proceed by contradiction: if $L_1-L_2<0$, then $c_n<0$ eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sequence $C_n=A_n-B_n\geq 0$ for all $n$. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}C_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n-\lim_{n\to\infty}B_n=L_1-L_2.$$
This statement follows from applying the triangle inequality to obtain
$$|(A_n-B_n)-(L_1-L_2)|\leq |A_n-L_1|+|B_n-L_2|$$
and looking at appropriately large values of $n$.

Then since $C_n$ is a sequence of nonnegative numbers, its limit is also nonnegative, for if $\lim_{n\to\infty} C_n=L<0$, then it is clear that $|C_n-L|\geq |L|$ for all $n$. So $L_1-L_2\geq 0$, i.e. $L_1\geq L_2$.

Comment: This is a circular reasoning! It is logically equivalent to the original question, and no explanation is given.

Comment: Please read the question: How can I use the *definition of limit*.

Comment: I have edited the references to the definition back into my answer.